# Drivers problem in Acer aspire a135-510p

Tags: drivers, acer

I recently installed ubuntu 22.4.3
On my laptop **Acer Aspire a135-510p ** and i am unable to use sound, Bluetooth,wifi,....any other function I can't find drivers for ubuntu on acer official website plz help me if anyone can ?

Comment: Try installing Ubuntu 23.10. Usually newer version of Ubuntu have better support for recent hardware.